# Get Latitude and Longitude from Annotation view

Tags: iphone, ios, mkannotation, mkannotationview

How do I get the latitude and longitude of an annotationView placed on my mapView? I need to get it when the rightAccessory gets tapped.

The `- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control` method does return the MKAnnotationView which has a `coordinate` property to be used. But I want the lat and long. How do I convert the coordinate to lat and long?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`coordinate` is a `CLLocationCoordinate2D`, which is a struct containing `latitude` and `longitude`.

`coordinate` is actually a property of `MKAnnotation`. `MKAnnotationView` has an `MKAnnotation` property named `annotation`.

So, in the method you mentioned you should be able to get to the latitude using `[[view annotation] coordinate].latitude` and longitude using `[[view annotation] coordinate]. longitude`.

Comment: That's because CLLocationCoordinate2D is, as benwong says, a struct, so it has no concept of methods or of getters. The C dot syntax for accessing struct members is the only correct method, though it's a completely understandable oversight since Apple's use of a struct here is kind of odd.

Answer (score 0):

Add  MKMapViewDelegate.

```
 func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView){      

let currentAnnotationLattitude = view.annotation?.coordinate.latitude

let currentAnnotationLongitude = view.view.annotation?.coordinate.longitude
        }
```